# Work with intervals using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df

```
num city    inc           pop
1,0 Абан    29343,00    8683,00
2,0 Агинское    25896,00    17496,00
3,0 Александровский Шлюз    21785,00    15063,00
4,0 Анапа   20000,00    70453,00
5,0 Апатиты 44057,00    57398,00
6,0 Арзамас 24000,00    104831,00
```

I need to print str, if `inc` less than User is typed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("01.xlsx")
price_flat = df['inc']
price_people = raw_input("Enter the summ, that you can pay at month: ")
for str in df:
    if price_people <= price_flat:
        print str
```

And print that str, where `np` in df differ from `np` that user typed on 10000.
For example, if I typed 30000 I should get all str where `np` from 20000 to 40000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the data frame only in the range: price_people ± 10000.

```
price_people = 30000
print( df[ ( df['inc'] >= price_people - 10000 ) & ( df['inc'] <= price_people + 10000 ) ] )
```

prints out:

```
   num city      inc       pop
0  1.0    A  29343.0    8683.0
1  2.0    B  25896.0   17496.0
2  3.0    C  21785.0   15063.0
3  4.0    D  20000.0   70453.0
5  6.0    F  24000.0  104831.0
```

Comment: It returns error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: You first need to be sure that `df['inc']` is of a numeric type. For example, you can make something like `df['inc'] = df['inc'].astype('float')`.